# Questions about the TikTok metadata

Tags: web-scraping, metadata, social-media, tiktok, tiktok-api

I was wondering if anyone knew about what some of the TikTok metadata means. This is metadata which can be found by looking at the JSON file which accompanies a video. This metadata can be found in dev tools or by web scraping. I'd like to know the meaning behind some of the keys in the JSON, like diggCount, playCount, and collectCount. In addition, does anyone happen to have any info on how often this data is updated? I'm also wondering if things like the diggCount below are rounded, so the values do not reflect the accurate value at the time of posting.

- Rhi

Metadata snippet:

`{ "id": "7277986355668438314", "desc": "I hope they enjoy their new home \u2764\ufe0f #homereno #beforeandafter #construction  We actually managed to completely renovate her house in 7 days \ud83d\ude33  Thanks @Emily Shaw and our construction team for making this happen!", "createTime": "1694538267", "scheduleTime": 0, "stats": { **    "diggCount": 2500000, "shareCount": 4346, "commentCount": 16800, "playCount": 16200000, "collectCount": "118252"** }, "nickname": "MrBeast", "authorId": "6614519312189947909", "authorSecId": "MS4wLjABAAAABKjQkOz_IIzXXzEAl_9LGsWhvK-gBnlczwRPXK8EmxAp6K3X0qiaP5_OEqmm0XwG", "avatarThumb": "https://p16-sign.tiktokcdn-us.com/tos-useast5-avt-0068-tx/54435a1ec165931f60f2a3872de74aa5~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1695236400&x-signature=FOzc8n8d8F6HCsXLKWIblmT5vcc%3D", "downloadSetting": 0, "authorPrivate": false, "capcutAnchorsOriginal": [], "capcutAnchors": [] }`

I don't know where to find a data dictionary or something explaining what the metadata means. Thanks!